# What is NetworkInterfaceType 53?

Tags: c#, .net, network-interface

I was working on a project this morning and encountered an interesting issue.  I noticed that sometimes [`NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype) contains a value that is not in the documented enum list, specifically a value of "53".  This interface is an OpenVPN connection and I've been able to work around it but it's certainly confusing.  Has anybody else encountered this issue?

```
private static void GetEndpoints()
{
    List<IPAddress> AddressList = new List<IPAddress>();
    NetworkInterface[] Interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    string Msg = String.Empty;
    foreach(NetworkInterface I in Interfaces)
    {
        Msg += String.Format("{0} ({1}) - {2}\r\n", 
            I.Name, 
            I.GetIPProperties()
                .UnicastAddresses
                .Where(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                ?.Address, 
            I.NetworkInterfaceType);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Msg);
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is just a [C++ ptr marshalled into C#](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/SystemNetworkInterface.cs,106) so I guess if the underlying structure returns something unexpected it will return something unexpected. I guess it's not supposed to be an expansive list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tracing the actual call to `GetAdaptersInfo` and the result `PIP_ADAPTER_INFO`, you can view the types defined in `Ipifcons.h` from [this source,](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/ipifcons.h) it is a virtual one.